# Change the background of a divider once input has been selected

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

having a blonde moment here, trying to use CSS to tell a divider to change its background once an input has focus.

```
<p>
    <label>Your Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="your_name" id="your_name" value="" />
    <div class="formhelper">Please enter your full name,<br />Character limit of 255</div>
</p>
```

Thats the HTML code, now I've tried the following but can't get it to work

```css
.appformwrapper input:focus + div {
    background-color: #CCC !important;
    display: block;
} 
.appformwrapper div ~ input:focus {
    background-color: #CCC !important;
}
.appformwrapper input:focus {
    background-color: #EEF;
}
```

Any ideas?  I've done this once before in CSS but can't find me blasted code :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not valid HTML to have a `div` in a `p`. Browsers will take your markup and treat it as this:

```
p
  label
  input
div
```

Which means your `div` actually comes after the `p`, rather than being inside it. So while you're trying to select a `div` that comes after an `input`, it won't work because the `div` doesn't exist in that position.

If you can change your `p` to another `div`, or your existing `div` to a `span`, your CSS should work. I'm not sure what exactly your second rule is supposed to do either, but it still won't work, as the general sibling selector `~` doesn't look at previous siblings.

Comment: Typical I just noticed the problem as you post the answer LOL It was meant to be a span :S I added the full working code onto your answer

Comment: @Neo: I think you'll want to post that as a separate answer, then pick either mine or yours to mark as accepted.